# Please I need explanation on this code below can someone help me out?

Tags: remix, tokens, solidity-0.8.x

Hello friends please am learning on Ethereum Development with remix and I got into a confusing code that I cannot explain. The mathematics is really confusing me. Can some explain this code to me I need to know why they are multiplying the tokenbalance of the owner with the token price then dividing it with the msg.value ...please help me

```
function purchaseToken() public payable {
    require((tokenBalance[owner] * tokenPrice) / msg.value > 0, "not enough tokens");
    tokenBalance[owner] -= msg.value / tokenPrice;
    tokenBalance[msg.sender] += msg.value / tokenPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the contract is used as a token market, of sorts.

If we forget the `require` line for a while, it seems it's used for transfering tokens from some owner to the transaction sender, and the sent `msg.value` stays in the contract. All token purchases are deducted from this same owner, taking into account the token price.

If we take a look at the `require` line, it.... doesn't make much sense. If all of the values at the left side of `(tokenBalance[owner] * tokenPrice) / msg.value > 0` are at least 1, then the expression is always true. So, regardless of what the token amount or token price is, if you simply provide even one *wei* as `msg.value`, the condition passes. So it's a rather useless condition.

Without knowing what the full idea of the function is, it may not be as broken as it sounds. The last two lines transfer the correct amount of tokens, regardless of the weird checks in the first line.